# How do I create different many to many relationships for the same two tables using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

I have 2 tables 'User' and 'Content'.
A user can favourite content, so I use a pivot table User_Content to establish the many to many relationship between the user and the content they have favourited.
This is fine.

A user can also purchase content. This would be the same relationship as above (User_Content) but would be completely different data.

How do I setup a relationship like this where the relationship between tables is the same but the content is different - can this be done successfully in Laravel using Eloquent?
Or is there a completely different way I should be approaching this?

Comment: I think you need to setup Polymorphic Relations. Read more about it on http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up a user_purchase and user_favorite table both containing user_id and content_id fields

then set up the model

as

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Content','user_purchase');
    }

    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Content','user_favorite');
    }
}

class Content extends Eloquent{

    public function buyers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_purchase');
    }

    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_favorite');
    }
}
```

The second column indicates which table to check for the many to many relationship

Comment: Perfect - This is exactly what I was after.